# Why all values of a nested hash are updated when merging another hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have following hash:

```
hash = {2021=>{:gastosCompra=>0}, 2022=>{:gastosCompra=>0}, 2023=>{:gastosCompra=>0}}
```

created as follows

```
headers = {
  gastosCompra: 'gastos compra',
}

elements = headers.inject({}) { |h, (k, _v)| h[k] = 0; h }

hash = Hash[years.collect { |item| [item, elements] }]
```

I am trying to update `gastosCompra` of `key year 2021`. I've tried `merge`, `deep_merge`, but unfortunately all the other keys are updated too:

```
hash[year][:gastosCompra] = 555
hash[year].merge!({gastosCompra: 555})
hash[year].deep_merge!({gastosCompra: 555})
```

This is the result:

```
hash = {2021=>{:gastosCompra=>555}, 2022=>{:gastosCompra=>555}, 2023=>{:gastosCompra=>555}}
```

Why all the nested hashes are updated if I just want to update year 2021? I guess I could loop over the keys and stop when I find the year 2021, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: I'm gona bet that all the values are in fact the same object. Check `hash.values.map(&:object_id)`. If it's all the same, please show us how you generated the hash

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that has been unmaintained for years? Also, what does this have to do with Ruby on Rails?

Comment: sorry, wrong tag.

Comment: yeah, all objects have same object id. The issue was not when updating, but when creating

Comment: The issue is here `Hash[years.collect { |item| [item, elements] }]`. I ended up looping and creating new objects for the nested hashes. Nice bet, thanks a lot for pointing it out @BroiSatse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object Id of all of them is same, you must make a copy of you `elements` hash.

all of them are referring to same address.

there is sallow copy in ruby with :

`Object#dup` : https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Object.html#method-i-dup

`hash = Hash[years.collect { |item| [item, elements.dup] }]`

or

`Kernel#clone` : https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Kernel.html#method-i-clone

you can use ActiveSupport for deep copy too: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_dup

Just for info -> see Ruby Marshal class, its useful for some cases : https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Marshal.html